# why does it say i need to "sign into my google account?"

Tags: updates

I use a nook as a tablet and I only have one account and I did sign into my google account but it won't let me update any of my apps and it's always saying "I need to sign into my google account" what do I do?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the error. At which stage does it give that error? Can you open Play Store and browse app or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Google apps like Google Play Services.

Comment: This is probably related.